# How do I use a client certificate to log in with Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I need to use a client certificate to log into a website to test it. I'm able to see how to configure them with the docs at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/client-certificates#Usage, but I can't seem to find any examples on actually using the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your certificates in /certs folder and link it in your cypress.config.ts file as follows. (There are 2 approaches one with a pfx file and other with cert+key):

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
    clientCertificates: [
        {
            url: 'https://federation-qa.mycompany.com/**',
            ca: [],
            certs: [
                {
                    pfx: 'certs/mycertificate.pfx',
                    passphrase: 'certs/mycertificate-passphrase.txt',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            url: 'https://federation-qa.mycompany.com/**',
            ca: [],
            certs: [
                {
                    cert: 'certs/mycertificate.crt.pem',
                    key: 'certs/mycertificate.key.pem',
                    passphrase: 'certs/mycertificate-passphrase.txt',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents() {
            // implement node event listeners here
        },
    },
});
```