# Client certificate example in Cypress

Tags: testing, automation, cypress, client-certificates

In Cypress documentation, it mentions how to add client certificates to Cypress.config file however it doesn't give any code example how to implement it inside a test case.
I was wondering if adding the certificate to config file in the project is enough or do I need also add any specific line of code to my test case?

Comment: Also see [How do I use a client certificate to log in with Cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73686777/how-do-i-use-a-client-certificate-to-log-in-with-cypress).

Comment: Yes it's enough unless you have some unusual requirement as in the linked question.